# Can't change both the colour and text in an element in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function in js to replace the element labelled as 'test' in a HTML document, 'test' is just a paragraph that reads "Hello world".

```
function doSomething(){
    document.getElementById("test")
    .style.color = "magenta";
    .textContent = "Goodbye";
```

It highlights the '.' before textContent, if I remove the '.' the text changes colour but it still says "Hello world"

Very new to JS so ik this probably has some easy fix but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can't chain multiple statements like that, assign your element to a variable (`const elm = document.getElementById('test')`) and then use it at the start of both assignments.

Comment: that is why you use constants or variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of an assignment (`obj.a = b`) is the value that was assigned, not the object you were using (and the `;` would have terminated the statement anyway). Instead, save the object reference to a variable/constant, then do two separate assignments:

```
function doSomething(){
    const element = document.getElementById("test");
    element.style.color = "magenta";
    element.textContent = "Goodbye";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for this:

```
function doSomething(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.color = "magenta";
    document.getElementById("test").textContent = "Goodbye";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your JavaScript code is the placement of the period ('.') without an object target. You should collect the element into a variable and specify you are trying to access a property of it before the period such as `element.textContent`.

```
function doSomething() {
    var element = document.getElementById("test");
    element.style.color = "magenta";
    element.textContent = "Goodbye";
}
```

Comment: Hi, can u explain what does the code do?

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to target the element twice, or this is not your main problem?

```
function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById("test")
        .style.color = "magenta";

    document.getElementById("test")
        .textContent = "Goodbye";
}
```